# Vue use v-bind with object for multiple props. How to use .prop modifier

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-component

I use a Component that has multiple props.
This is my code and works very well

```
const val = {
    text: 'a', value: 'b'
}
const text = 'some text';

<template>
    <some-component :myVal.prop="val" :someText="text" />
</template>
```

I want to combine this using v-bind
And I have to use **.prop** modifier for passing object/array prop to web component.
(https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-bind)

So I try like this.

```
const multipleProp = {
    'myVal.prop': { text: 'a', value: 'b' },
    someText: 'some text'
}

<template>
    <some-component v-bind="multipleProp" />
</template>
```

But It doesn't works.
And I have a lots of props in "some-component", so I want to use a single one v-bind.
How to use **one v-bind** in this case?

Comment: You bind multiple properties to a component using ```v-bind``` but you use the ```.prop``` with an object of properties, which is not supported. The ```.prop``` can only be used with a specific prop name.

Comment: Thanks. I have to use a lot of web component and each component has a lot of primitive/object props. So It's very hard working to define each prop in template area. There are any good idea using one v-bind?

Comment: Declare a new data property for each prop you want to bind to the component and use ```v-bind``` to bind these data properties to the corresponding props on the component. By doing it, you can still use ```v-bind``` to bind multiple props to the component, while still being able to use the ```.prop``` for the specific prop that requires it.

Comment: I don't understand. could you plz write the code? In question, const multipleProp = {
    'myVal.prop': { text: 'a', value: 'b' },
    someText: 'some text'
}
It's not working.

Comment: See [Passing DOM properties](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html#passing-dom-properties) to web components. You probably want `<some-component v-bind="multipleProp" .myVal="multipleProp.myVal" />`, which passes `myVal` as prop, rather than attribute

Comment: I want single v-bind. Because I have a lot of props.

Answer (score 0):

> Declare a new data property for each prop you want to bind to the component and use v-bind to bind these data properties to the corresponding props on the component. By doing it, you can still use v-bind to bind multiple props to the component, while still being able to use the .prop for the specific prop that requires it.

```
data() {
 return {
    myValProp: { text: 'a', value: 'b' },
    someText: 'some text'
 }
}


<template>
 <some-component v-bind:myVal.prop="myValProp" v-bind:someText="someText" />
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do.
Just using

```
<template>
    <some-component v-bind.prop="multipleProp" />
</template>
```

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean  it doesn't works,it seems no errors and I [test it here](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: You should make your someComponent as a web component.
And make myVal props type as Object.

Comment: there are no error. but prop's doesn't passed to someComponent.

Comment: Its hard to to imagine what do you want as you did't show the someComponent